# Как перейти по ссылке в Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на LiknLabel в Winforms открывался браузер и совершался переход по ссылке?(C#)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например вот так откроется ссылка в браузере по умолчанию:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var url = linkLabel1.Text; //адрес ссылки это значение свойства `Text`
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
}
```

Указать конкретный браузер можно так:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var url = linkLabel1.Text;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IExplore.exe", url);
}
```